# Symfony2 form type class not found

Tags: symfony

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\Type\PreferencesIcecatType' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\InterfaceICEDBP\src\DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Controller\PreferencesIcecatController.php on line 66
```

I am trying to create e form clase so it is reusable and i have followed [the manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-creating-form-classes).

I am using symfony 2.3.4, in Windows with XAMPP

I've already tried to clear the cache in both enviroments, restart apache and MariaDB, Do you have any clue? Thank you very much!

I have done other type for other form I have and it works perfectly, so i think is something wrong in some where but not related with namespaces.

This is my Controller, it is in the folder \src\DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Controller

```
namespace DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Entity\Preicedbp\category;
use DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Entity\Preicedbp\supplier;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\Type\PreferencesIcecatType;



class PreferencesIcecatController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $categories = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\Category')->getAllCategories();
        $categories = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\Category')->getCategoriesJSON($categories);

        $suppliers = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\Supplier')->getAllSuppliers();

        $distributors = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\Distributor')->getAllDistributors();
        $distributors = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\Distributor')->getDistributorsJSON($distributors);

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.catId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpCategories c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.catId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $categories_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $cat) {
            $categories_selected .= $cat['catId'].",";
        }
        //$categories_selected = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Category')->getCategoriesSelectedJSON($categories_selected);

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.distributorId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpDistributors c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.distributorId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $distributors_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $dist) {
            $distributors_selected .= $dist['distributorId'].",";
        }

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.supplierId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpSuppliers c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.supplierId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $suppliers_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $sup) {
            $suppliers_selected .= $sup['supplierId'].",";
        }

        $preferences = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpPreferences')->find(1);

        $pref_id = $preferences->getId();

        $options = array('suppliers_selected'=>$suppliers_selected, 'id'=>$pref_id);
        $form = $this->createForm(new PreferencesIcecatType(),$options);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            //Obtenemos los datos del formulario
            $form->bind($request);
            $datos = $form->getData();

            $datos->setTypeUpdate(1);
            //Guardamos imp_preferences automáticamente
            $em->persist($datos);
            $em->flush();

            //Recogemos las categorias, suppliers y dist que se guardan a parte
            $cat_selected = $form["cat_selected"]->getData();
            $sup_selected = $form["sup_selected"]->getData();
            $dist_selected = $form["dist_selected"]->getData();


            //Primero borramos lo que hay para luego insertarlo de nuevo (así me olvido de mirar si está ya insertado o no).
            $query = $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpSuppliers c WHERE c.idImpPreferences='.$pref_id);
            $query->getResult();

            $query = $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpDistributors c WHERE c.idImpPreferences='.$pref_id);
            $query->getResult();

            $query = $em->createQuery('DELETE FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpCategories c WHERE c.idImpPreferences='.$pref_id);
            $query->getResult();

            $categorias = explode(",",$cat_selected);
            foreach($categorias as $cat) {
                if(empty($cat)) continue;
                $conn = $em->getConnection();
                $query = "INSERT INTO imp_categories VALUES($pref_id,$cat)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute(array());
            }

            $fabricantes = explode(",",$sup_selected);
            foreach($fabricantes as $sup) {
                if(empty($sup)) continue;
                $conn = $em->getConnection();
                $query = "INSERT INTO imp_suppliers VALUES($pref_id,$sup)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute(array());
            }

            $distribuidores = explode(",",$dist_selected);
            foreach($distribuidores as $dist) {
                if(empty($dist)) continue;
                $conn = $em->getConnection();
                $query = "INSERT INTO imp_distributors VALUES($pref_id,$dist)";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
                $stmt->execute(array());
            }




            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'La configuración se ha guardado con éxito!!');
        }

        //Aquí vuelvo a sacar las categorias seleccionadas porque al cambiar tengo que volver a sacarlas.

        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.catId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpCategories c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.catId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $categories_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $cat) {
            $categories_selected .= $cat['catId'].",";
        }
        //$categories_selected = $em->getRepository('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Category')->getCategoriesSelectedJSON($categories_selected);

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.distributorId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpDistributors c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.distributorId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $distributors_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $dist) {
            $distributors_selected .= $dist['distributorId'].",";
        }

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT c.supplierId FROM DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preicedbp\ImpSuppliers c WHERE c.idImpPreferences=1
                ORDER BY c.supplierId ASC');

        $_selected = $query->getResult();
        $suppliers_selected = "";
        foreach($_selected  as $sup) {
            $suppliers_selected .= $sup['supplierId'].",";
        }

        return $this->render('DBPInterfazIcedbpBundle:Preferences:icecat_preicedbp.html.twig', 
                array('categories'=>$categories, 'suppliers'=>$suppliers, 'distributors'=>$distributors,
                        'categories_selected'=>$categories_selected, 'distributors_selected'=>$distributors_selected, 'suppliers_selected'=>$suppliers_selected,
                        'preferences'=>$preferences,'form' => $form->createView()));
    }       

}
```

And this is my Type in \src\DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\Type

```
<?php
namespace DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\DataTransformer\StringToArrayTransformer;

class PreferencesIcecatType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $suppliers_selected = $options['suppliers_selected'];
        $pref_id = $options['id'];

        //añadimos las categorias, fabricantes y distribuidores en un campo hidden
        $builder->add('cat_selected', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => '', 'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('sup_selected', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => $suppliers_selected,'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('dist_selected', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => '','mapped'=>false,
        ));


        $builder->add('id', 'hidden', array('data'=>$pref_id,'property_path'=>'id'));
        //$builder->add('id', 'hidden', array());

        //Añadimos el resto de campos
        $builder->add('onMarket', 'choice', array('label'=>'Mercado','choices'   => array(
                '0'   => 'Sólo productos que no estén en el mercado',
                '1' => 'Sólo productos en el mercado',
                '2'   => 'Todos'),'multiple'  => false));

        $builder->add('quality', 'choice', array('label'=>'Calidad','choices'   => array(
                'ICECAT'   => 'ICECAT',
                'SUPPLIER' => 'SUPPLIER',
                'NO-EDITOR'   => 'NO-EDITOR',
                'TODOS'=>'TODOS'),'multiple'  => false));

        $builder->add('importProducts', 'choice', array('label'=>'Filtrar por','choices'   => array(
                '1'   => 'Categorias',
                '2' => 'Fabricantes',
                '3'   => 'Distribuidores',
                '0'=>'TODOS'),'multiple'  => false,'expanded'=>true));

        //$entityManager = $options['em'];
        $transformer = new StringToArrayTransformer($em);
        $builder->add($builder->create('languages', 'choice', array('label'=>'Lenguajes','choices'   => array(
                'ES'   => 'ES',
                'EN' => 'EN',
                ),'multiple'  => true,'expanded'=>false))->addModelTransformer($transformer));

        $builder->add($builder->create('countryMarket', 'choice', array('label'=>'Mercado','choices'   => array(
                'ES'   => 'ES',
                'EN' => 'EN',
        ),'multiple'  => true,'expanded'=>false))->addModelTransformer($transformer));

        $builder->add('onlyUpdateExistings', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Actualizar sólo existentes',
                'required'  => false,
        ));

        $builder->add('sel_cat', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Seleccionar/Deseleccionar',
                'required'  => false, 'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('sel_sup', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Seleccionar/Deseleccionar',
                'required'  => false,'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('sel_dist', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Seleccionar/Deseleccionar',
                'required'  => false,'mapped'=>false,
        ));

        $builder->add('show_only_cat', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Mostrar sólo seleccionadas',
                'required'  => false,'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('show_only_sup', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Mostrar sólo seleccionados',
                'required'  => false,'mapped'=>false,
        ));
        $builder->add('show_only_dist', 'checkbox', array(
                'label'     => 'Mostrar sólo seleccionados',
                'required'  => false,'mapped'=>false,
        ));



        $builder->add('user_icecat', 'text', array( ));
        $builder->add('pass_icecat', 'text', array( ));
        $builder->add('icecat_route', 'text', array( ));
        $builder->add('icecat_subdir', 'text', array( ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'preferences_icecat';
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same problem using a FormType and MongoDB....  Although I have not had this issue with MySQL and FormType classes.

Comment: No, I didn't solve it, sorry :( it is the only form I have included inside the controller :( I will try to fix it again some day, when I do I will update this post. Ask your question again with your code, maybe your problem is easier.

Comment: I figured mine out, I had the file in the wrong folder I had it in form not in type. maybe you did too?

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your controller:

```
use DBP\InterfazIcedbpBundle\Form\Type\PreferencesIcecatType;
```

The error says that cant found your form class, so say it where it is.

Comment: It is in the controller, in line 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a typo error. In your use in your controller, the name of your FormType file, the name of your FormType class. Check the namespaces.